# Coding a discord bot- The clear/purge command suddenly won't work

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I took a small break from coding my bot, and I've been playing around with adding modules to make an economy type thing. I was having some issues with that, so I went to check if the 'clear' command worked still. I originally wrote the code without the async function, but now I am using it and I think maybe that has caused a problem?
Wondering if anyone knows how to fix it, thanks for checking this out.

The ban/kick commands also aren't working at all, so if anyone could take a look at those?

For the code, I've used bits and pieces of tutorials and guides from around the internet and I think some of that may have interfered with what's already been written.

```
if (command === 'clear') {

    const deleteCount = parseInt(args[0], 10);

    if(!deleteCount || deleteCount < 2 || deleteCount > 300)
        return message.reply('Please provide a number between 2 and 300 for the number of messages to delete.')

        const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({deleteCount});
        message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
            .catch(error => message.reply(`I couldn't delete the messages because of: ${error}`));
    }

//kick command

if (command === 'kick') {

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(`KICK`)) return message.reply('You have insufficient permissions.')

    if(!member.kickable) return message.reply('I cannot kick this user!');

    if(user){
        const member = message.guild.member(user);

        if(member){
            member.kick('You have been kicked.').then(() =>{
                message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}.`);
            }).catch(err =>{
                message.reply('I was unable to kick the specified member.');
                console.log(err);
            });
        } else {
            message.reply("That user is not in this server.")
        }
    } else {
        message.reply('You need to specify a user!')
    }

}
```

When running the command, for example, `~clear 3`, it will often say:

> 'I couldn't delete the messages because of: DiscordAPIError: You can only bulk delete messages that are under 14 days old.' Even if the previous messages are only minutes/seconds old.

Other times when using `~clear 3` (usually a few minutes after the above messages were sent) it will delete more than just three.

When using `~kick` it won't respond at all.

Comment: did you try ``message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: deleteCount});`` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me as well, the bot tries to delete all the messages in the channel (likely due to a discord.js update). However, there is a work-around:

````
exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
     if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "Staff"))
        return;
  const amount = args[0]
if (!amount) return message.reply('Must specify an amount to delete!');
message.channel.fetchMessages({
 limit: amount,
}).then((messages) => {
 message.channel.bulkDelete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
});
message.delete().catch(O_o => { });
}```

You may also want to downgrade your discord.js version.
````

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the late reply, but this helped tons. <3

Comment: As of now, downgrading is not an option anymore. You'll run into limitations and weird issues due to Discord's API changes.